# how to use regexExtract() extract spcified values in dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image]

The source data is like the photo. I am new to data flow and expression language. I wonder how to use regexExtract()(or any other expression function) to extract only the genres' names.

The expected output should be:
Animation
Comedy
Family
Adventure
Fantasy
...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression `split(split(genres,"'name':'")[2],"'")[1]` to achieve this.

I create a csv file which contains your sample data.

[image]

Use the above expression in DerivedColumn transformation and get your expected value.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful!

Comment: @Saxia Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in)? Thanks a lot.